# Rails 4.1 enum wrong where conditions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, enums

Today i want change my Postgres enum to [Rails 4.1 enum](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v4.1.0/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html).
I make some steps.

migrations:

```
 create_table :users do |t|
   # other column here
   t.column :status, :integer
 end
```

in model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  enum status: [ :local, :tourist ]
end
```

now create user:

```
  => User.create(email: 'ffoo@mai.com', password: '12345678', status: 'local')
  => #<User id: "53621ec84d6163124", email: "ffoo@mai.com", status: 0, ......>
  => u = User.last
  => User Load (0.9ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" ........
  => #<User id: "53621ec84d6163124", email: "ffoo@mai.com", status: 0, ......>
  => u.local?
  => true
```

Try find local users(and now i have strange behavior of my enum):

```
  => User.where("status <> ?", User.statuses[:local])
  => User Load (0.9ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE (status <> 0)
  => []
```

WTF?

```
  => User.where("status <> ?", User.statuses[:tourist])
  => User Load (0.9ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE (status <> 1)
  => #<User id: "53621ec84d6163124", email: "ffoo@mai.com", status: 0, ......>
```

So problem, this query `User.where("status <> ?", User.statuses[:local])` should return my local user. Or i doing something wrong?

Comment: By the way, since I wasn't the first one to make this mistake:  https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/16460

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using a wrong operator here.

```
"status <> ?" equals  "status != ?"
```

Instead you want to use

```
"status = ?"
```

[Postgres comparison operators](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/functions-comparison.html)